# Randomly selecting a unique element in a 2D Array

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi so I'm doing an assignment but I've kind of fallen flat on the concept of 2D arrays. I'm writing a method body that randomly selects an element in a 2D array. However, I'm not completely sure when of how to approach the problem.

I was thinking of using a random number generator to select a random element. Although what I need first is for the whole length of the box to be filled first with a value. In this case, the dimensions of the 2D array box are 20x20 and the value is zero. So I'd want the 2D array to be complete filled with zeroes. Although if I used a random number generator, is there a chance that an element which was randomly selected by the generator could possibly be used again before the entire box dimensions are filled first with zero?

Sorry for the long block of text. Basically what I'm asking is if there is a way to use random number generator to still randomly generate numbers but not repeat any its used previously.

Comment: You could populate an array with numbers from 0 to 19, shuffle it and iterate over it. You'll get unique number each time.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076147/how-to-generate-numbers-from-an-array-randomly-with-each-number-being-unique?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095185/how-to-randomly-generate-a-unqiue-number-from-an-array-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `Collections.shuffle(allCells)`.

Another option is to use the following algorithm, by keeping track of remaining unused cells:

```
1. Find a random number from 0 to size of the set - 1 .
2. Remove number at position `randomNumber` from the set.
3. Go to 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go this way:

```
        int [][] myArray = new int[4][5]; //Any size and type
        int totalEmenent = myArray.length *myArray[0].length;
        int indexToSelect = (int)(Math.random()*totalEmenent);
        int xIndex = (int)indexToSelect/myArray.length;
        int yIndex = indexToSelect%myArray.length;
        int selectElement = myArray[xIndex][yIndex];
```

If you wish to select unique index each time:

```
        int [][] myArray = new int[4][5]; //Any size and type
        int totalEmenent = myArray.length *myArray[0].length;
        String selectedIndex = "";
        int numberOfSelect = 10; //Any number< totalEmenent

         for(int indx=0; indx< numberOfSelect; indx++){
              int indexToSelect = (int)(Math.random()*totalEmenent);
              //generate random until its unique
              while(selectedIndex.indexOf(String.valueOf(indexToSelect))> 0){
                   indexToSelect = (int)(Math.random()*totalEmenent);
              }
              selectedIndex = selectedIndex+indexToSelect;
              int xIndex = (int)indexToSelect/myArray.length;
              int yIndex = indexToSelect%myArray.length;
              int selectElement = myArray[xIndex][yIndex];
         }
```

Comment: Randomly selecting a *unique* element - if this code were looped, it would potentially pick the same element multiple times. Not unique.

Comment: I still don't get why you would ever want to "generate random until it's unique"... when you can merely make sure it's ALWAYS unique (see my answer)

Comment: @BillJames Say in first run random value is 5, 5%400 = 5. In second run its 5 again in that case 5%399 = 5 again. Duplicate. Am I missing something from your answer?

Comment: @Yogendra yes, because the value in locations[5] will change from the first time as it's swapped with locations[399] that first time it was selected.

Comment: @BillJames  Ohh I see now. You are manipulating the original array, which I was trying to avoid. I just tried to access not update the array.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I'm manipulating my temporary array that I created for the express purpose of doing so... yes.  Basically, I'm guaranteed that, whatever value cap has, all the values in locations[0..cap] have not yet been used... so I don't have to test whether it's been used or not.

Comment: @BillJames: Got it, thanks for helping me to understand your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I read above... you want to fill a 20x20 2D array with 0's, but you want to do it by selecting a random location in the array each time, and you don't want to "re-fill" a slot.

The fastest way to do this is to create an array with all the possible locations (in this case, that's 0..399, if you figure that the value/20 = the first index, and value%20 = the 2nd index, e.g. 125 = array[125/20][125%20] or array[6][5], see?)

so, first, fill this array locations[400] with the values 0..399.

```
int [][] box = new int[20][20];
int [] locations = new int[400];
for ( int i = 0; i < 400; i++ ) locations[i] = i;
```

Then, starting with a cap of 399, generate a random number loc from 0 to cap, and use the locations[loc] as your current index to fill with a 0, then swap the locations[loc] with locations[cap], decrease cap by 1, and continue.  By the time cap reaches 0, you'll have used all the locations.

```
int cap = 399;
Random rand = new Random();
while ( cap >= 0 ) {
    int rnd = rand.nextInt(cap+1);
    int loc = locations[ rnd ];
    box[loc%20][loc/20] = 0;   // Here's where we set the value 0 into the 2D array
    // now swap the location selected with the value at the "end" of the current list.
    // hmm, forget the swapping, let's just bring that value in from the end.
    locations[rnd] = locations[cap];
    cap--;  // "shrink" the current list, eliminating the value we just put at the end from consideration.
}
```

That should do it.  You should be able to see that this will never pick the same value out of the "locations" array, since the swap at the end of the loop puts that locations value outside the boundary of index 0 to cap.  The next time through the loop, it's impossible to select that value again (or any other value that's already used).

Comment: `rand.nextInt();` produces negative values and will cause an array index out of bounds exception.

Comment: k, lemme fix that.  The API says that using the nextInt(int arg) produces a value from 0 .. (arg-1), so I'll use that instead.

Comment: Changed my swap to only copy the value from the "end" to the currently selected location, since I don't care about maintaining the part of the locations array that I'll never use again.

Answer (score -1):

While populating your array, you can have an arraylist to add the index of each cell(say i,j), and then generate random number

```
Arraylist<int[]> ar=new Arraylist();
//inside loop for populating array
    yourArray[i][j]=whatever;
    ar.add({i,j});
//loop ends

int index=new Random().nextInt(ar.size());
int[] arrayIndex=ar.get(index);
ar.remove(index);
row=arrayIndex[0];
column=arrayIndex[1];
(Type)randomElement=yourArray[row][column];
```